# I keep getting an "ModuleNotFoundError" with Django in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I know, this is a common problem, but no solution has yet worked for me.
I have set up Django with an Virtual Environment in Python (on Windows) but everytime I try to run `django-admin startproject mysite` I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Max\Desktop\django_app\venv\Scripts\django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.core import management
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

Does anybody know a solution for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In `pip list` does it show django inside it?

Comment: @theheavycoder it actually does. So it is installed but I do get this error.

Comment: Did you run `pip list` while you were inside the virtual environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I have done all the setup on cmd and copied all my commands if you any issue you found ask me
```

Moreover kindly set environment variable in accordance to and check it out on google

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1110]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Dell>python --version
Python 3.8.5

C:\Users\Dell>django --version
'django' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Dell>pip --version
pip 20.2.4 from C:\Users\Dell\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)

C:\Users\Dell>pip install virtualenv
Collecting virtualenv
  Downloading virtualenv-20.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.3 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 5.3 MB 45 kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.0.0 in c:\users\dell\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from virtualenv) (3.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: six<2,>=1.9.0 in c:\users\dell\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from virtualenv) (1.15.0)
Collecting platformdirs<3,>=2
  Downloading platformdirs-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting backports.entry-points-selectable>=1.0.4
  Downloading backports.entry_points_selectable-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.2 kB)
Collecting distlib<1,>=0.3.1
  Downloading distlib-0.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (338 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 338 kB 76 kB/s
Installing collected packages: platformdirs, backports.entry-points-selectable, distlib, virtualenv
Successfully installed backports.entry-points-selectable-1.1.0 distlib-0.3.2 platformdirs-2.0.2 virtualenv-20.6.0

C:\Users\Dell>python -m venv DjangoFolder

C:\Users\Dell>DjangoFolder\Scripts\activate

(DjangoFolder) C:\Users\Dell>python -m pip install django
Collecting django
  Using cached Django-3.2.5-py3-none-any.whl (7.9 MB)
Collecting pytz
  Using cached pytz-2021.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
Collecting sqlparse>=0.2.2
  Using cached sqlparse-0.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
Collecting asgiref<4,>=3.3.2
  Using cached asgiref-3.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Installing collected packages: pytz, sqlparse, asgiref, django
Successfully installed asgiref-3.4.1 django-3.2.5 pytz-2021.1 sqlparse-0.4.1
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 21.2.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\Dell\DjangoFolder\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

(DjangoFolder) C:\Users\Dell>DjangoFolder\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-21.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.6 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.6 MB 49 kB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 20.1.1
    Uninstalling pip-20.1.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-20.1.1
Successfully installed pip-21.2.1

(DjangoFolder) C:\Users\Dell>cd DjangoFolder

(DjangoFolder) C:\Users\Dell\DjangoFolder>cd lib

(DjangoFolder) C:\Users\Dell\DjangoFolder\Lib>cd site-packages

(DjangoFolder) C:\Users\Dell\DjangoFolder\Lib\site-packages>python -m django --version
3.2.5

(DjangoFolder) C:\Users\Dell\DjangoFolder\Lib\site-packages>cd ..

(DjangoFolder) C:\Users\Dell\DjangoFolder\Lib>cd ..

(DjangoFolder) C:\Users\Dell\DjangoFolder>python -m startproject mysite
C:\Users\Dell\DjangoFolder\Scripts\python.exe: No module named startproject

(DjangoFolder) C:\Users\Dell\DjangoFolder>cd mysite
The system cannot find the path specified.

(DjangoFolder) C:\Users\Dell\DjangoFolder>python -m django startproject mysite

(DjangoFolder) C:\Users\Dell\DjangoFolder>cd mysite

(DjangoFolder) C:\Users\Dell\DjangoFolder\mysite>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 18 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
July 25, 2021 - 23:49:45
Django version 3.2.5, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.

(DjangoFolder) C:\Users\Dell\DjangoFolder\mysite>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_000`enter code here`2... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
  Applying auth.0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK

(DjangoFolder) C:\Users\Dell\DjangoFolder\mysite>python manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected

(DjangoFolder) C:\Users\Dell\DjangoFolder\mysite>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
July 25, 2021 - 23:50:46
Django version 3.2.5, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK
[25/Jul/2021 23:53:33] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 10697
[25/Jul/2021 23:53:34] "GET /static/admin/css/fonts.css HTTP/1.1" 200 423
[25/Jul/2021 23:53:35] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 86184
[25/Jul/2021 23:53:35] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 85876
[25/Jul/2021 23:53:35] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 85692
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[25/Jul/2021 23:53:37] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2110[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0QdI.jpg
```

Comment: My pleasure that i helped you

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have 2 pythons installed?

What version of python are you using?

Try to install with pip3

`python -m pip install django`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried it but it just returns the same error. I have `Python 3.9.6` installed.

Answer (score 1):

Did you activate your virtual environment?
If yes then check if Django is installed there by typing in terminal/cmd.

```
pip list
```

it should give you a list of packages installed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did activate the virtual environment and "pip list" returns that Django is installed: `Django     3.2.5`.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the virtual environment, then install it. Virtual environments can only use packages installed while you are in it.

So when you are inside, run `python -m pip install django`, you may have to replace python with python3 and pip with pip3.